# MS Word correct when printing, not when viewing document

Tags: printing, ms-word, export

I have a Word document generated from an external tool (BIRT 4.3.0) which contains 2 parallel tables.

The problem is that the 2 table should be aligned on top, but they're not always. If you look at the below picture, we can see that the table cell isn't positioned at the same place for both tables.

However, the problem is only when viewing the document, the document is 100% correct when printing it. Also, we're not seeing the problem on all machines (we're using both Word 2010 and 2013).

We tried to change lots of printer setting, printer driver, Word options, but couldn't find a way to have the 2 tables top aligned when looking at the doc.

We're pretty sure the issue is related with the printer setting and/or with a "hidden" Word option ...

Did anyone already see a similar behavior?

Comment: Can you post the document itself somewhere (feel free to remove irrelevant content and anonymise the data)

Answer (score 0):

I actually solve the issue by applying the following fix : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822005